# The definition of continuity for linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to prove that a linear functional is continuous on the space $H^1(0,l)$, and I have a couple of different definitions. The one that I want to use is that $f$ is continuous if $f$ is continuous at $0$. However, I guess that I am confused as to what "$0$" actually is in the context of functionals. Is $0$ the equivalence class of functions that are $0$ a.e.? Or, if I am looking at a functional $f(v)$, would $f(0)$ be $f(v(0))$?

I know that this is a pretty basic question, I'm just starting to look at functional analysis, I really appreciate any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words "$f$ is continuous at $0$" indicate that $0$ is an element of the domain of $f$. The domain of $f$ is the space $H^1(0,l)$. So, in this context $0$ means the zero element of this normed vector space.

To go further, one needs to go back to the definition of the space $H^1(0,l)$ to find out what exactly its elements are. Then you'll find they are equivalence classes of functions, up to equality a.e.